# Can I use CCMenu with Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, ccmenu

I'd like to use CCMenu with my Gitlab project's CI pipelines. What is the feed URL for the CI pipelines of a Gitlab project? Does one exist?

What I've tried that didn't work:

- https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2/pipelines/cc.xml (which I didn't expect to work)
- https://gitlab.com/(username)/(project)/-/?scope=running , https://gitlab.com/(username)/(project)/-/jobs , and /-/pipelines etc

The research I've done:

- It seems that https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/26858 has not been resolved.
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/10805 was closed without being merged 11 months ago.
- Some other project besides CCMenu added support for Gitlab CI, but I don't see XML anywhere, so I believe they're parsing gitlab's HTML webpage. https://github.com/matryer/bitbar-plugins/blob/master/Dev/Gitlab/gitlab_ci.1m.py
- I don't understand what this is: https://github.com/joblift/gitlab-panorama